# PHP Soap Client Errors

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to use a web service provided by a third party organisation.

The URL for the service is [this](http://dev.portal.swisshoteldata.ch/ws/export/exporthoteldata.cfc?wsdl)

This is what I've tried:

```
$sc = new SoapClient( $my_wsdl_url, array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
        ) );
```

**First problem:** When checking for the provided functions, I get a UNKNOWN type:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "UNKNOWN getDeletedHotels()"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "UNKNOWN getMasterData()"
  [2]=>
  string(44) "UNKNOWN getHotelData(dateTime $dRequestDate)"
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486703/php-soapclient-getfunctions-returning-unknown-types), but I have no access to the SOAP-Server. So, how can I change settings in my SOAP-Client in order to get the correct return types?

Nevertheless, I tried to call the above function `getHotelData()`, but it takes about 2 minutes to get a response. And the response is an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http 
body, No Content-Length, connection closed or chunked data in [...]
```

There are several posts with the same error message. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652705/error-fetching-http-body-with-php-soapclient) here and tried it by adding these settings to the client:

```
 $sc = new SoapClient( $my_wsdl_url, array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create( array( 
                'http' => array( 
                    'protocol_version' => 1.0 
                ) ) );
        ) );
```

After that, the server is not responding at all!

So, I am a little bit stuck here. Can somebody push me in the right direction?

PHP-Version is 5.4.19, on a mac running xampp

**Update**

I reduced the above code to the minimal requirements (without the login stuff), but still I cannot get the complete list.

When testing with one of Amazon's Webservices, I get a complete list of all available functions.

```
$sc = new SoapClient( 'http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl', array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
) );

// List all functions. This works
var_dump( $sc->__getFunctions() );
```

So, could it be that the webservice itself is not setup correctly?

Comment: Provide your WSDL, which generate PHP object.

Comment: Credentials for this server are ok, can use them for testing?

Comment: @Piotr Olaszewski: Updated my question. I'm afraid, I'm not allowed to provide the credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a working solution, inspired by this answer here: [Sending Raw XML via PHP SoapClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608314/sending-raw-xml-via-php-soapclient-request/17053242#17053242) after getting the required request XML by using the software from http://www.soapui.org/